# SQL Server : how to TRIM a special character and UPDATE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim, azure-synapse

I'd like to remove the leading and trailing `*` character from the column `CONDITIONDESCRIPTION` and `UPDATE` it.

I find the syntax like

```
SELECT TRIM('*' FROM '***SOLD W/MATCHING TRAILER***') AS TrimmedString;
```

on W3School. But it doesn't update the table.

What I tried is

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Auct_Car]
SET CONDITIONDESCRIPTION = TRIM (CONDITIONDESCRIPTION, '*');
```

And it ends up with an error

> Query complete with error

Comment: why are you using a different syntax for `TRIM` when doing the update?...just use the same syntax you used in the `SELECT`

Comment: Yea, I tried and it doesn't work. It give `It gives Incorrect syntax near 'FROM'`

Comment: "Syntax for Azure Synapse Analytics" here shows you are out of luck https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest and will have to use a `PATINDEX` solution

Comment: Have you checked if that character occurs only at the beginning and end of strings? If so you can use `REPLACE`

Answer (score 0):

Azure Synapse Analytics doesn't support the `characters FROM` component of `TRIM ( [ characters FROM ] string )`

You need to do something like

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Auct_Car]
SET CONDITIONDESCRIPTION = SUBSTRING(CONDITIONDESCRIPTION, 
                                     PATINDEX('%[^*]%', CONDITIONDESCRIPTION + 'x'), 
                                     LEN(CONDITIONDESCRIPTION + 'x') -PATINDEX('%[^*]%', REVERSE(CONDITIONDESCRIPTION)) -  PATINDEX('%[^*]%', CONDITIONDESCRIPTION + 'x') + 1);
```

or just `REPLACE` the `*` with an empty string if there is no possibility that these may exist other than at string ends.

[Test cases](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f1565ae86a0fde59f22f61f18ae97f0)